# KivyMD using MDToolbar produces error: self._shadow = App.get_running_app().theme_cls.quad_shadow

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

Whenever I use MDNavigationToolbar or MDToolbar widgets I get the error

```
message line 111, in _update_shadow
     self._shadow = App.get_running_app().theme_cls.quad_shadow
```

I've read a lot of the information out there on this topic and followed this example:

[Error: In _update_shadow self._shadow = App.get_running_app().theme_cls.quad_shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57129106/error-in-update-shadow-self-shadow-app-get-running-app-theme-cls-quad-sha)

I followed the steps exactly and it stopped the crashes but all I had was a blank screen for my app, I couldn't see the Toolbar (even after playing around with the colours)

```
class LoginWindow(Screen):
    pass


class CreateAccountWindow(Screen):
    pass


class QrScannerWindow(Screen):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_file("mykivy.kv")
sm = WindowManager()

screens = [LoginWindow(name="login"), CreateAccountWindow(name="create account"), QrScannerWindow(name="qr scanner")]
for screen in screens:
    sm.add_widget(screen)

sm.current = "qr scanner"

class MyApp(App):
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()

    def build(self):
        return sm
```

kv file:

```
WindowManager:
    LoginWindow:
    CreateAccountWindow:
    QrScannerWindow:

<QrScannerWindow>:
    name: "qr scanner"

    NavigationLayout:
        MDNavigationDrawer:
            NavigationDrawerToolbar:
```

Answer (score 1):

While **[KivyMD](https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD)** is in *alpha* status, it may have bugs. KivyMD widgets expect that on their initialization app object already created.

Please create all widgets inside *build* function:

```py
    def build(self):
        kv = Builder.load_file("mykivy.kv")
        sm = WindowManager()

        screens = [LoginWindow(name="login"), CreateAccountWindow(name="create account"), QrScannerWindow(name="qr scanner")]
        for screen in screens:
            sm.add_widget(screen)

        sm.current = "qr scanner"
        return sm
```